# Is there any value for $x$ that would make the statement $(x+3)^3 = x^3+3^3$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Is there any value for $x$ that would make the statement $(x+3)^3 = x^3+3^3$ true?

I understand that when factored out, you have $(x+3)^3 = x^3+9x^2+27x+27$ as opposed to the other side which is $x^3+27$, so even if you plug in $0$ the left side will always be greater. Is this the right thinking process for determining the answer? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Note:  the r.h. is $x^3+27$ not $x^3+9$, as you have written.

Comment: Hint:  after expanding (correctly...please check your expansion), cancel the common terms.  What's left is a quadratic that factors easily to reveal the possible values for $x$.

Comment: You have an error in expanding the lefthand side as well.  $(x+3)^3 = \binom{3}{0}x^33^0+\binom{3}{1}x^23^1+\binom{3}{2}x^13^2+\binom{3}{3}x^03^3 = x^3+9x^2+27x+27$

Comment: By inspection, $x=0$ and $x=-3$ work. There can be no more solutions. For *imagine* expanding (it is safer than expanding). We will get a quadratic equation, which can have no more than $2$ roots.

Comment: $x = 0$ the trivial solution, and $x = -3$

Comment: my apologies, i made some stupid calculation errors which is why i wasn't getting the right answer. thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x+3)^3 = x^3+3^3$

$\Leftrightarrow x^3+9x^2+27x+27 = x^3+27$

$\Leftrightarrow 9x^2+27x = 0$

$\Leftrightarrow x^2+3x = 0$

$\Leftrightarrow x(x+3)=0$

$\Leftrightarrow x=0$ or $x=-3$

Answer (score 2):

I have to mention this, though applying it to this case is rather uninteresting. There's a result in abstract algebra called "the freshman's dream." If $p$ is prime and $R$ is a ring in which $\underbrace{1+1+1+\cdots+1}_{p\ \mathrm{times}}=0$ then
$$(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$$
for all $x,y\in R$. Thus if we work, say, in the ring of integers modulo $3$, then
$$(x+3)^3=x^3+3^3$$
However, $3=0$ in this ring, so this is merely saying that $x^3=x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

${(x+3)^3 = x^3 + 3^3}$

Expand

${x^3 + 9x^2 + 27x + 27 = x^3 + 27}$

Cancel

${9x^2 + 27x = 0}$

Factor

${x(9x + 27) = 0}$

${9x(x + 3) = 0}$

Therefore ${x = 0, x = -3}$

Answer (score 0):

$(x+3)^3 - (x^3 + 3^3) = 9(x)(x+3) = 0 $

Hence the solutions are $-3$ and $0$.